# How can I launch my service with notification by timing

Tags: android

I'm working now with android to build an application that can launch notification everyday.
Now I have a code that lunch a background service with a notification. I know that I have to use alarm service for pick the right time, but I don't know how to modify the code the make it service or notification display in one time everyday on the same time.

Code(**`MainActivity.java`**):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editTextInput;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_input);
}

public void startService(View v) {
    String input = editTextInput.getText().toString();

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);

    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
}

public void stopService(View v) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}
}
```

**`App.java`**

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    createNotificationChannel();
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Example Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);

    //do heavy work on a background thread
    //stopSelf();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the problem you need to resolve. Is it the Notification you can't trigger?

Comment: I want to launch my notification daily in one time, like I want to execute the notification on 8:00PM

Answer (score 1):

alarm manager application to display notification:

Mainactivity.java:

```
TimePicker timePicker;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting the timepicker object
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAlarm);
    //attaching clicklistener on button
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //We need a calendar object to get the specified time in millis
            //as the alarm manager method takes time in millis to setup the alarm
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        timePicker.getHour(), timePicker.getMinute(), 0);
            } else {
                calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
            }


            setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        }
    });
}

private void setAlarm(long time) {
    //getting the alarm manager
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);

    //creating a pending intent using the intent
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

    //setting the repeating alarm that will be fired every day
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Myalarm.java:

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

//the method will be fired when the alarm is triggerred
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //you can check the log that it is fired
    //Here we are actually not doing anything
    //but you can do any task here that you want to be done at a specific time everyday
    addNotification(context);
    Log.d("MyAlarmBelal", "Alarm just fired");
}
private void addNotification(Context context) {
    // Builds your notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    builder.setContentTitle("John's Android Studio Tutorials");
    builder.setContentText("A video has just arrived!");

    // Creates the intent needed to show the notification
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context , 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a service to just show a notification. Use alarm manager with broadcast receiver and write down your code to show alarm in the onReceive of the broadcast receiver.

Comment: You can improve your answer with implementation, instead of just comments

Comment: But I need to make my notification works in time even user close my app

Comment: Yeah alarm manager will do that. search a little about it. Have a look at this link https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: But I tried to make an alarm manager application before, and I found when I close my app (App is dead) notification will never display. (U will found hall of code in first anwer)

Comment: alarm may not call at exact same time. as in android orio google has made major changes related to battery optimization. time me vary upto 15 minutes. But for sure alarm is called either your app is alive or not.

Comment: I took 2-3 days to read about these things when i was working on a similar functionality and I came to know about many new things, i learned alot from them. You too search more about background jobs it will definatly add to your knowledge base .

Comment: Thank you I will, but for now I sure that the alarm (my second code) can run with some difference?